# Batch file to archive a directory and delete older 7z archive

Tags: windows, batch-file, 7zip, backups

I've been using the following batch file to backup a certain directory on a Windows Server machine for a long time. The batch file is run by a Windows Scheduled Task every day at a certain time and it zips a specific folder to a backup location after deleting the oldest .7z file (7z = www.7-zip.org).

This way I only ever have the number of .7z files specified in BackupNr in my backup folder and I don't have to manually delete the oldest .7z file.

The problem is the "Set BackupNr=1" line. Using BackupNr=1 I always have TWO .7z archives in my backup folder after the batch file has run.

I can't figure out what I need to change so that only ONE archive is kept whenever the batch file runs. How can I fix this?

```
@echo off

:: The name of the backup file that will be created. It will use the current date as the file name.
@For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do @(
    Set FileName=%%A%%B%%C%%D
)

:: The name of the folders where all the backup .zip and report files will be stored.
Set ArchiveFolder=D:\Backup\Manual\Archives
Set ReportFolder=D:\Backup\Manual\Reports

:: The name of the folder that will be backed up, i.e. the AppData folder.
Set FolderToBackup=C:\AppData

:: The number of .zip files and .txt reports to keep. Older archives will be deleted according to their age. This ensures we only keep the most recent X number of backups.
Set BackupNr=1

:: Delete oldest backup archives so we only keep the number of archives specified in "skip=".
echo.>> DeletedBackups.txt
date /t >> DeletedBackups.txt
echo.>> DeletedBackups.txt
echo These older backups were deleted:>> DeletedBackups.txt
for /F "skip=%BackupNr% delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o-d %ArchiveFolder%\*') do (
    echo %ArchiveFolder%\%%a%1>> DeletedBackups.txt
    del /f /q %ArchiveFolder%\%%a%1
)

echo.>> DeletedBackups.txt
echo These older reports were deleted:>> DeletedBackups.txt
for /F "skip=%BackupNr% delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o-d %ReportFolder%\*') do (
    echo %ReportFolder%\%%a%1>> DeletedBackups.txt
    del /f /q %ReportFolder%\%%a%1
)

echo Starting the backup: %DATE% %TIME% >> %ReportFolder%\%FileName%.txt

:: Adds all files to 7z archive using BCJ2 converter, LZMA with 8 MB dictionary for main output stream (s0), and LZMA with 512 KB dictionary for s1 and s2 output streams of BCJ2.
C:\PROGRA~1\7-Zip\7z.exe a -t7z %ArchiveFolder%\%FileName%.7z %FolderToBackup%\* -m0=BCJ2 -m1=LZMA:d23 -m2=LZMA:d19 -m3=LZMA:d19 -mb0:1 -mb0s1:2 -mb0s2:3 >> %ReportFolder%\%FileName%.txt

echo Backup finished at: %DATE% %TIME% >> %ReportFolder%\%FileName%.txt

:: Write the backup Start and End times to the BackupInfo.csv file.
gawk -f BackupRecord.awk %ReportFolder%\%FileName%.txt >> %ReportFolder%\BackupReport.csv

:: Write the file size of the backup .zip file that was just created to the log file.
set size=0
call :filesize %ArchiveFolder%\%FileName%.7z
echo Backup archive file size: %size% bytes >> %ReportFolder%\%FileName%.txt

exit

:: set filesize of 1st argument in %size% variable, and return
:filesize
  set size=%~z1
  exit /b 0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /b switch in the dir command uses no header nor summary. result is a plain list of archives, in this case orderer descending by creation time, the most recent first.

The problem is the *skip=%BackupNr%* in

```
for /F "skip=%BackupNr% delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o-d %ReportFolder%\*') do (
  echo %ReportFolder%\%%a%1>> DeletedBackups.txt
  del /f /q %ReportFolder%\%%a%1
)
```

as skip the first line, so the delete command erases all archives EXCEPT the most recent.

then you execute the backup, so a new file is added to the directory. Result, two files.

If you want only the last one, you should first perform the backup and after the deletion, or remove the *skip=%BackupNr%* from the for command.